# Richfaces 4 rich:inputNumberSpinner: not getting "set" in backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have done JSF work before, but am new to RichFaces.  To test my set up and environment, etc.  I have tried to make just a simple little app where the user enters two numbers, clicks a button, and the app returns the sum and product of the numbers.

Here's the code summary:

```
web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

 <display-name>eSPAR</display-name>

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Plugging the skin into the project -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>deepMarine</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

Next:

```
faces-config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<application></application>

</faces-config>
```

In other words, basically empty except for the version declarations.  Next comes the view page:

```
 addmult.xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>

<rich:panel header="Sample Add and Multiply App">
<h:form id="addmultForm">

    <p>Enter one number here: 
        <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="num1" minValue="0"
                            value="# {calcBean.number1}" /></p>
    <p>Enter another number here: 
        <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="num2" minValue="0"
                           value="#{calcBean.number2}" /></p>

    <a4j:commandButton value="Go" action="#{calcBean.go}" immediate="true">
        <f:ajax event="click" render="results" />
    </a4j:commandButton>

    <br /><br />

    <h:panelGroup id="results">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{calcBean.calcDone}">
        <p>The sum of your two numbers is: #{calcBean.sum}</p>
        <p>The product of your two numbers is: #{calcBean.product}</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>


</h:form>
</rich:panel>   

</h:body>   
</f:view>
```

Now finally the bean:

```
 CalcBean.java
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class CalcBean {

private Integer number1 = 3;
private Integer number2 = 7;
private int sum;
private int product;
private boolean calcDone = false;

public Integer getNumber1() {
    System.out.println("I am number1: " + number1);
    return number1;
}
public void setNumber1(Integer number1) {
    System.out.println("Change in number1");
    this.number1 = number1;
}
public Integer getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}
public void setNumber2(Integer number2) {
    this.number2 = number2;
}

public int getSum() {
    return sum;
}
public int getProduct() {
    return product;
}
public boolean isCalcDone() {
    System.out.println("Returning calcDone: " + calcDone);
    return calcDone;
}


public String go() {
    System.out.println("Going!");
    sum = number1 + number2;
    product = number1 * number2;
    calcDone = true;
    return null;
}

}
```

My WEB_INF lib contains: commons-beanutils-1.8.3, commons-collections-3.2.1, commons-digester-2.1, commons-logging-1.1.1, cssparser-0.9.5, guava-r08, jhighlight-1.0, jsf-api (mojarra 2.0 version), jsf-facelets-1.1.15, jsf-impl (again mojarra 2.0), richfaces-components-api-4.0.0-FINAL, richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0-FINAL, richfaces-core-api-4.0.0-FINAL, richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0-FINAL, sac-1.3, standard.

Whatever values I initiate the Integers number1 and number2, those are the values initially in the inputs when the page loads.  The lower text is initially hidden.  When the "Go" button is clicked, the lower panel appears, but no matter what values the user has entered, the sum is always 10 and the product always 21 (as shown).

The sysout in the setter never displays.  The one in the getter displays once when the page loads.  When "Go" is clicked, the sysout "Going!" shows once, then "Returning calcDone: true" shows six times.

What I have tried: Changing the scope of the bean.  Wrapping the expressions in the results panel in `<h:outputText>`.  Adding the FaceletViewHandler in web.xml (actually causes more problems).  Removing the facelet jar file from the lib.

Do I need a value change listener on the inputs?  What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Go" action="#{calcBean.go}" immediate="true">
    <f:ajax event="click" render="results" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Remove `immediate="true"`. It will cause the inputs which do **not** have `immediate="true"` to be completely skipped in processing. Also remove `<f:ajax>` as `<a4j:commandButton>` already uses ajax. To get a better understanding what `immediate` does and what you need it for, I suggest you to get yourself through this article : [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) (yes, it's JSF 1.2 targeted, but general concept applies on JSF 2.x as well)

Here's a summary of relevance:

> ### [Okay, when should I use the immediate attribute?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute)
>
> If it isn't entirely clear yet, here's a summary, complete with real world use examples when they may be beneficial:
>
> - If set in `UIInput`(s) only, the process validations phase will be taken place in apply request values phase instead. Use this to prioritize validation for the `UIInput` component(s) in question. When validation/conversion fails for any of them, the non-immediate components won't be validated/converted.
> - If set in `UICommand` only, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s). Use this to skip the entire processing of the form. E.g. "Cancel" or "Back" button.
> - If set in both `UIInput` and `UICommand` components, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s) which does not have this attribute set. Use this to skip the processing of the entire form expect for certain fields (with immediate). E.g. "Password forgotten" button in a login form with a required but non-immediate password field.

So, you ultimately want this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Go" action="#{calcBean.go}" render="results" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: there are more pretty serious problems in your configuration. I have the impression that you're reading JSF 1.x and RichFaces 3.x targeted tutorials/documentation instead of JSX 2.x and RichFaces 4.x targeted ones. The first `<context-param>` is mandatory for JSF 1.x Facelets only and the remnant is all specific to RichFaces 3.x. Remove them all. You also have an offending JSF 1.x `jsf-facelets.jar` file which should be removed as well as JSF 2.x already bundles a JSF 2.x Facelets implementation.

Comment: You are half-right.  I am viewing JBoss's docs for Richfaces 4, but as those *do not say* how to set up web.xml, I had taken my cues from prior (MyFaces Trinidad, 1.2 and 2.0) projects I had done.  So here is where I am now: 1) Removed the facelets jar.  2) Stripped web.xml down to just the servlet and servlet mapping.  3) Changed my button to: `<a4j:commandButton value="Go" action="#{calcBean.go}" reRender="results" />`  I am now seeing the new values of the inputs in the bean via sysouts.  But now the results panel does not re-render, it stays hidden.

Comment: RF4 requires no single line of `web.xml` and `faces-config.xml` configuration :) I thought this was explicitly mentioned somewhere in its doc as well? As to rendering, use `render` attribute of `<a4j:commandButton>`, sorry overlooked that part in my suggestion, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I edited the answer and checked the docs: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces-Using_RichFaces_in_existing_JSF2_projects *"In RichFaces 4, it is not necessary to add any extra settings to the web.xml or config.xml settings files to use the framework."*

Comment: Yee-hah.  Looks like they changed the name of that attribute from reRender in verision 3.3 to just render in 4.0: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/vdldoc/.  Many thanks once again.

Comment: So, you're familiar with RF 3.3? For 3.3. to 4.0 migration I've found this doc very helpful, you may find it helpful as well: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration (particularly the section "components migration"). If you're using Eclipse, the newest JBoss Tools should also help a lot in autocompletion and showing tag documentation in editor.

Comment: Familiar? No.  Exposed to? Yes.  Plus, and most annoyingly, even when you explicitly type "Richfaces 4" Google seems to prefer 3.3.  I've been taking care to bookmark the newer docs when I come across them.  And I will look into those JBoss tools.

Comment: Use "richfaces4" as keyword instead, without the space.