# Updating command link value in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a command link and on its click i have a dialog in JSF 2.0 as:

```
<p:commandLink  value="(.3%)" style="font-size:10px;" onclick="lrDlg.show()"     id="percentchange"/>
```

Now on the dialog i want the value of command link value as:

```
<h:outputText value="Change Value" />
<h:panelGroup>
<p:inputText size="10" value="#{bean.changeValue}" required="false"
styleClass=" ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all " />
<h:outputText value="" style="font-size:10px;" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

My Question is how i update the value in inputtext so as to reflect in commandlink value(shown as "(.3%)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a bean property.

```
private String commandLinkValue;

public Bean() {
    commandLinkValue = "(.3%)";
}

// ...
```

with

```
<p:commandLink value="#{bean.commandLinkValue}" ...>
```

and

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.commandLinkValue}" ...>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. i have done the above steps but i have to update on buttons click on which i am updating the corresponding id like <p:commandButton value="Save" action="closecurrentdialog" update="percentchange" ajax="false" immediate="true" /> but the changes are not taking place.

Comment: You need to remove `immediate="true"` so that the submitted input value will be processed. To learn when (not) to use `immediate="true"`, read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636008/richfaces-4-richinputnumberspinner-not-getting-set-in-backing-bean/7636245#7636245

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to update the input-field value before you show the dialog:

Give an `id` to the input-field:

```
<h:inputText id="inputFldId" value="Change Value" />
```

Javascript function:

```
function updateFldAndShowDlg() {
    var btnVal = jQuery("#percentchange").text();
    jQuery("#inputFldId").val(btnVal);
    lrDlg.show();
}
```

Use above function on the command-link `onclick` event:

```
<p:commandLink  value="(.3%)" style="font-size:10px;" onclick="updateFldAndShowDlg()"     id="percentchange"/>
```

Comment: Psssh, that's not an input text.

Comment: @BalusC: Isn't that what he is trying to do? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: You said input-field, but you wrote `<h:outputText>`.

Comment: @BalusC: Oh, I just copied it from the OP. Didn't even notice it. Thanks.

Comment: He was using `<p:inputText>`, that might have been the cause of the confusion.